Increasing Tap-to-Click Sensitivity for an M1 MacBook Pro Running Mac OS Sequoia 15.1.1 (24B91)
After many enthusiastic years on Mac trackpads I now have arthritis that requires Tap-to-Click. The feature worked well on my old Intel MacBook Pro but my refurbished M1 is unresponsive at least 25% of the time. Are there any options for increasing sensitivity to my taps?
